# how to attach files that are stored in the database to the action mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, email-attachments

you have mention about how to store files in database.
How to attach those files with mail using action mailer?
I have search many sites but not able to find the way to attach database files.
Everywhere the help of attaching files stored in file system is given.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very different from sending attachments stored on disk.

Say you have a model `Binary` that corresponds to files in the file system. If it responds to `content_type` and `data`, then something like this should work:

```
class AttachmentMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def attachment(recipient, binary)
    recipients recipient
    subject "Your requested file"
    from "example@example.com"

    attachment :content_type => binary.content_type, :body => binary.data
  end
end

# Wherever you want to e-mail something:
binary = Binary.find(:first)
Notifier.deliver_attachment("user@example.com", binary)
```

Of course, if you store your data differently or if the database columns are named differently, you should adjust the methods of the `Binary` class (or whichever class you use) in the above example.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks molf.
you have solved my problem almost.
the only remaining thing is :filename => binary.filename (# here binary.filename means binary table and filename is a column which stores filename).
So it is done!